# Postgresql get the distinct values with another max value

Tags: postgresql, max, distinct

I have a table with this values:

```
id - idProduction - historical - idVehicle - km
1  -      200     -      1     -     258   - 100
2  -      200     -      2     -     258   - 100
3  -      200     -      2     -     259   - 150
4  -      200     -      3     -     258   - 120
5  -      200     -      3     -     259   - 170
6  -      300     -      1     -     100   - 80
7  -      100     -      1     -     258   - 140
8  -      300     -      2     -     325   - 50
```

I need to get the values with the max historical, for all the distinct idProduction. In that case:

```
4  -      200     -      3     -     258   - 120
5  -      200     -      3     -     259   - 170
7  -      100     -      1     -     258   - 140
8  -      300     -      2     -     325   - 50
```

It my first work with postgresql, so I don't have to much idea on how to do it, does anyone can help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with that I can solve my problem, but I'm not sure... :

```
SELECT id, productions_vehicles.id_production, nu_task_number, id_historical, id_vehicle
FROM productions_vehicles
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id_production, MAX(id_historical) AS idHistorico
    FROM productions_vehicles
    GROUP BY id_production) topHistorico 
ON productions_vehicles.id_production = topHistorico.id_production 
AND productions_vehicles.id_historical = topHistorico.idHistorico;
```

Answer (score 1):

You effectively need two requests, your solution looks good, you can also use the `WITH` clause to do the first request :

```
WITH topHistorico (
    SELECT id_production, MAX(id_historical) SA idHistorico
    FROM productions_vehicles
    GROUP BY id_production)
SELECT id, pv.id_production, nu_task_number, id_historical, id_vehicle
FROM production_vehicles pv
INNER JOIN topHistorico th ON pv.id_production = th.id_production AND pv.id_historical = th.idHistorico
```

[PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.1: WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html)